# How to load downloaded image dataset (the300w_lp) in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load 300W_lp dataset in tensorflow.
I downloaded and extracted the dataset manually at C:/datasets/the300w
Now when I try to load dataset into tensorflow using

```
the300w = tfds.load('the300w_lp',data_dir='C:\datasets\the300w', download=False)
```

it gives me error

```
Dataset the300w_lp: could not find data in C:\datasets\the300w. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.
```

Please help. How to load dataset in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use plain old

```
dataset = tfds.load('the300w_lp')
```

It works fine for me. Maybe You somehow incorrectly unzipped the dataset file? If you have spare time, try the above code and see if it works.

Comment: Had to use ```the300w, info = tfds.load(
    'the300w_lp', data_dir='/downloadeddataset/the300', split='train', with_info=True)``` to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple way to tackle this issue. Simply run the above command in google colab, grab a portion of the dataset object, download it and use it for your own purpose :)

Comment: `Simply run the above command` you have not written any command